# Craete an archive which includes the current folder

Tags: batch, 7-zip

I want to create an archive which contains the folder, which I am zipping.
My  challenge is, that I want to exclude some files from the root of the directory, but not from its sub-directories.

Let's say I have this structure:

```
Dir1
    SubDir1
        composer.json
    composer.json
```

My goal is to have an archive like this:

```
Dir1
    SubDir1
        composer.json
```

I want to exclude the composer.json within Dir1, but not in SubDir1. I Also want to keep the folder "Dir1" within the archive.

In order to keep "Dir1", I did this:

```
del %dirname%.zip
FOR /F %%i IN ('cd') DO set dirname=%%~nxi
cd ..
7z a -tzip %dirname%/%dirname%.zip %dirname% -mx0 -x!composer.json
cd %dirname%
```

Unfortunately, this won't skip the composer.json, because it's in a sub-dir from the perspective of my script. When I use `-xr` it would also skip the composer.json from `SubDir1`.

When I run this script from inside of Dir1, I would have the effect I am looking for, but Dir1 would not be included in my archive:

```
del %dirname%.zip
FOR /F %%i IN ('cd') DO set dirname=%%~nxi
7z a -tzip %dirname%.zip * -mx5 -x!composer.json
```

I see two possible solutions here where I would need assistance for:

1. How can I exclude only files from `Dir1` but not its sub-dirs?
2. Is there any other way how I can include the directory in my archive?

Answer (score 0):

As a non expert zipper nor an expert batcher, I would :

- add at the top of the script a line for moving the file, which you don't want to include, to a directory higher
- and then at the end move it back to its initial position.
  But this way of doing is +/- OK only if there is ONE file to exclude and always the same and **if you don't know what to do else**.

```
del %dirname%.zip
#### Moving the file a directory higher
mv %dirname%\composer.json ..
FOR /F %%i IN ('cd') DO set dirname=%%~nxi
cd ..
7z a -tzip %dirname%/%dirname%.zip %dirname% -mx0 -x!composer.json
#### Moving it back 
mv composer.json %dirname%
cd %dirname%
```

I will be listening to this thread, because a better answer might interest me !
IF I find a better and more 7zip way to do this, I will update my answer.

Yours,

SPOUKI